# Is it possible to replace two opposite and different functions with a single one?

Tags: javascript, function, optimization

I want to optimise and reduce my code to increase performance and correct-ability of it. With those two different functions below I can successfuly move a `Google Map Marker` on a map forward and backward using a `pathIndex`, calcuted on an array of GPS coordinates [I didn't include this section of code since I think it's not releated to this question but I can and will post it if needed].

This is my code:

**1st function**:

```
function animate() {
    if (pathIndex < coord.length && mapAnimationStatus != PLAY_PAUSED) {
        googleMapsMarker.setPosition(coord[pathIndex]);
        googleMap.panTo(coord[pathIndex]);

        pathIndex += 1;

        if (pathIndex == coord.length) {
            pause();

            pathIndex = 0;
            mapAnimationStatus = NOT_PLAY;

            return;
        }

        timerHandler = setTimeout("animate(" + pathIndex + ")", 1000);
    }
}
```

**2nd function**:

```
function animateRewind() {
    if (pathIndex >= 0 && mapAnimationStatus != PLAY_PAUSED) {
        googleMap.panTo(coord[pathIndex]);
        googleMapsMarker.setPosition(coord[pathIndex]);

        if (pathIndex == 0) {
            pause();

            mapAnimationStatus = NOT_PLAY;

            return;
        }

        pathIndex -= 1;

        timerHandler = setTimeout("animateRewind(" + pathIndex + ")", 1000);
    }
}
```

As you can see those two functions shares a lot of portions of code and it think that they can be replaced with a single one for this reason but I can't figure out how to do this.

So, is it possible to create a single `function` to manage those two different animations?

Comment: Could you swap the `panTo` and `setPosition` calls? Can you swap the `pathIndex = 0;` with the `pause` call? If so, I'd have a rather simple solution

Comment: Why do the `animate` and `animateRewind` calls in the `setTimout`s take a parameter?

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean by "swap the pathIndex"?

Comment: Will your functions do the same if you exchange the two statements (swap the two lines)?

Comment: @Bergi no they won't :-/

Comment: What a pity. I didn't think they would influence each other…

Comment: "shares a lot of portions of code": I don't agree with that. These two functions differ more than they are similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I didnt miss something...

```
function animate(pathIndex, dir) {
    var animateDir = (pathIndex < coord.length
        && mapAnimationStatus != PLAY_PAUSED && dir == 'f')
            ? dir
            : (pathIndex >= 0
            && mapAnimationStatus != PLAY_PAUSED && dir == 'r')
            ? dir : "error";

    if (animateDir === "r") { googleMap.panTo(coord[pathIndex]); }
    if (animateDir !== 'error') { googleMapsMarker.setPosition(coord[pathIndex]); }
    if (animateDir === "f") {
        googleMap.panTo(coord[pathIndex]);
        pathIndex += 1;
    }

    if (animateDir !== 'error') {
        if (pathIndex == coord.length || pathIndex == 0) {
            pause();
            pathIndex = animateDir === "f" ? 0 : pathIndex;
            mapAnimationStatus = NOT_PLAY;
            return;
        }
        pathIndex = animateDir === "f" ? pathIndex - 1 : pathIndex;
        timerHandler = setTimeout("animate(" + pathIndex + "," + animateDir + ")", 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is looking much more complicated than the original two functions.

Comment: Yeah it turned out rather complicated, I wonder if the order of pan and setposition matters, and also Im confused about the parameter that the original author included for the function, oh well...

Comment: Yeah, I asked for clarification about that from the OP before attempting to answer :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
function ConcatenateFunctions() {
    if(mapAnimationStatus != PLAY_PAUSED){
        googleMap.panTo(coord[pathIndex]);
        googleMapsMarker.setPosition(coord[pathIndex]);

        if (pathIndex < coord.length) {
            pathIndex += 1;
            if (pathIndex == coord.length) {
                pause();
                pathIndex = 0;
                mapAnimationStatus = NOT_PLAY;
                return;
            }
        }else if (pathIndex >= 0) {
            if (pathIndex == 0) {
                pause();
                mapAnimationStatus = NOT_PLAY;
                return;
            }
            pathIndex -= 1;
        }

        timerHandler = setTimeout("ConcatenateFunctions(" + pathIndex + ")", 1000);
    }
}
```

Hope it will help !

Comment: I didn't downvote you, and a quick read looks like you've pretty much answered the question.  However, the `setTimeout` parameter should be `ConcatenateFunctions` instead of `animate`.  (Or you could rename the function to `animate`.)  Also, `pathIndex` should be added as a parameter to the function or removed from `setTimeout`.  This is a problem with OP's code as well.

Comment: @RickHitchcock My mistake (the animate) just fixed it! but from what I took from the code above, he's using them in this way, I only concatenated them in a way to work.. I have no clue from where the pathIndex is coming from...

Comment: `pathIndex` is either a global variable, or OP's functions are inside another function.  It's fine to leave `pathIndex` in the `setTimeout` – it just doesn't do anything.  It's the equivalent of writing `setTimeout(ConcatenateFunctions, 1000)`.